# How to multiply table with a constant in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two tables in a sheet: Distance table and Cost Table

Some routes don't have a distance value yet.
What I want is that every time I add a value in the distance table, the Cost table will autofill the values by multiplying a constant number.

The constant number is 2 because it costs $2 per kilometer.

ie. The distance from B to A is 50kilometeres; the value in cost table should be 100 because every distance costs $2.

Is there any faster way in multiplying the table without typing the formula individually in each cell?

Here is a sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lx9WN1NW2KChYZCWTU1M1UAwYhre3l6jVtLResihVa8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I duplicated your sheet and entered in the cell with the yellow background

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(B9:T27), B9:T27*2,))
```

See if that works for you?

#### Reference:

- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)